# SSRS Conditional Formatting

Tags: reporting-services

I have a simple *List* in my report, with a single row and a single column (which is repeated depending on the number of items returned by the query).

What I'd like to do is this:  Inside the cell (in the same location), display one rectangle full of items (text boxes, images, etc) for even rows, and another (with different items) for odd rows.

What is the recommended way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this for the **Hidden** property of the Rectangles:

```
=IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, true, false)
```

Use a different order for `true` / `false` for each of the two Rectangles to get them to alternate.

All the expression is doing is checking if a row number is even and setting the visibility based on this.

This is a pretty standard SSRS pattern which is typically used for alternating row colours, but it should work the same for showing/hiding items.

Comment: Thanks Ian -- I was concerned about plopping the 2 rectangles right on top of each other in the designer, but Visual Studio does appear to be handling that real estate encroachment well.  I've implemented this approach and it appears to work great!

Comment: Great, glad it helped! It's always a pleasant surprise when SSRS gets rendering right in cases like this.